# Difference between $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$

Tags: limits, notation, summation

Is there any difference between $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$?

My example and thought:

Let $a_n=n$ where $n\in\mathbb{P}$. $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all positive integer.

Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\rightarrow\infty$$

And

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k=-\frac{1}{12}.$$

Am I thinking right?

Comment: How do you define $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$?

Comment: @GitGud Sum of all members of ${a_k}$.

Comment: That's an infinite sum, it isn't defined.

Comment: @GitGud Then, is $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ wrong notation? Or we define $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k:=\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k$?

Comment: @Novice, exactly right. Check your books.

Comment: @vonbrand I'm sorry but I've commented two conditions. Which one is right? Is it wrong or we define as ... ? My book uses both notations though.

Comment: @Novice, sorry. By *definition*, $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k$ is the limit (if it exists) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$. The limit doesn't exist when $a_k = k$.

Comment: It seems to me, and I know this was a long time ago and all, but it seems to me that you are correct. This is proper. The reason is that both forms are correct Mathematically, although the second one is on the odd and slightly insane side of mathematics. The first time I saw it I had a brain aneurism. I at least thought I had one. Anyway, you, or at least were correct, anyway, the world of Mathematics is insanely crazy and pretty cool as well.

Comment: Oh my god... again the same question over the Ramanujan summation xD. About the notation as other said they are equivalent. But for represent the series itself, not it limit, generally is written as $\sum x_n$ or $\sum_{n\ge C} x_n$ if needed, then we can say that $\sum x_n\to x$ if the series converges to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite sums are defined as limits of their partial sums. So in this sense they are equivalent.

What you are using in your example is a Zeta regularization of a divergent series. In that sense, even the equality sign is not really justified. $-1/12$ is not the sum in the traditional sense, it's a generalization and you have to specify what you are doing.

Comment: I'm getting more confusing now. Git Gud said in the comment that infinite sum is not defined, but you are saying that infinite sums are defined as limits of their partial sums, which is $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k:=\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k$. I don't know what zeta regulation is though. I've just read the proof of sum of all natural number is $-1/12$ which has clearly proved.

Comment: The particular sum that you stated is not defined, I'm sure that's what Git meant. In general it is defined as a limit (one of the definitions). If you are not really well versed in mathematics, I suggest that you completely ignore the sum of natural numbers, it will just confuse you. It is evident that it totally diverges in any traditional sense. Regularization works by somehow "subtracting" infinity or "wrap it around" to assign a finite value to some sums. It has meaning in its own field of mathematics, but it doesn't really mean anything in the context of your question. Read up on wiki.

Comment: Ok, I've just read the definition of series, no reason to be a not well versed in mathematics at least in this case. If the sequence of partial sums of $\{a_n\}$; $\{S_n\}$ converges, then we define the _infinite series_ $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n:=\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$. And the sum of all natural number is also derived in traditional way. I've read the proof of it but it was clearly proved without using any contemporary mathematical theories.

Comment: Let $S_1:=1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$. We can easily observe that $S_1=1-S_1$, $S_1=1/2$. Now, let $S_2:=1-2+3-4+5-6+7-\cdots$. Then $2S_2=S_1=1/2$, $S_2=1/4$. And let $S:=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+\cdots$. Consider $S-S_2=4S$, then $3S=-S_2=-1/4$. Therefore, $S=-1/12$.

Comment: In this case, the "f the sequence of partial sums of {an}; {Sn} converges" does not apply. The series is divergent. If you want to play around with this idea, you can also look at the $1+q+q^2+q^3\cdots=1/(1-q)$ and use $|q|>1$. You are using a series outside its convergence radius (just like with $1+2+3+\cdots$), so in the traditional sense, the sum doesn't exist. You are **extrapolating** to get a generalized notion of the sum.

Comment: I know. The case that I mentioned $\{a_n\},\{S_n\}$ in the comment is just a definition. I didn't mean that $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a red herring; the standard way of interpreting the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k$ is that it diverges to infinity, although there are some theories of divergent series which would assign the sum a different value. In any case, the two limits in your question are exactly equal: an infinite series is *defined* to be the limit of its partial sums.